# JDBC Source Connector for Confluent cloud?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

IS JDBC SOURCE Connector available for Confluent Cloud?
I want to connect Snowflake with Confluent cloud kafka topics.

Comment: If it's not listed in your account, it's not available and you'll need to run your own Kafka Connect cluster. Snowflake has its own connector, by the way

Comment: Snowflake sink connector is available for confluent cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC Source connector is available on Confluent Cloud for several RDBMS ([Oracle](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-oracle-db-source.html#cc-oracle-db-source), [MS SQL](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-microsoft-sql-server-source.html#cc-microsoft-sql-server-source), [MySQL](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-mysql-source.html#cc-mysql-source), [Postgres](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-postgresql-source.html#cc-postgresql-source)) - but not others, including Snowflake.

In this scenario you'd need to run a Kafka Connect worker yourself, connecting to Confluent Cloud. For example: https://rmoff.net/2021/01/11/running-a-self-managed-kafka-connect-worker-for-confluent-cloud/